# Overlapping ranges error when sending larger file

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to upload ~47M file with 4M chunks through `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable` but keep getting 416 with "Overlapping Ranges" error.

Chunks are send with `Content-Range` header as follow:

```
"bytes: 0-4194303/47992832"
"bytes: 4194304-8388607/47992832"
"bytes: 8388608-12582911/47992832"
"bytes: 12582912-16777215/47992832"
"bytes: 16777216-20971519/47992832"
"bytes: 20971520-25165823/47992832"
"bytes: 25165824-29360127/47992832"
"bytes: 29360128-33554431/47992832"
"bytes: 33554432-37748735/47992832"
"bytes: 37748736-41943039/47992832"
"bytes: 41943040-46137343/47992832"
"bytes: 46137344-47992831/47992832"
```

For each chunk `Content-Length` is 4194304 but last one which is 1855488. Seems to me that Requests are correct and I don't know where to look on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranges provided look ok to me, but this API requires a 'Session-Id' in the request header. That 'Session-Id' should be the same for every requests to upload a file in chunk. But must be different each time. If you are using the same 'Session-Id' to upload files (or the same file), you'll get that error, because a range will be recorded twice or overlap with a previous call. In short generate a new 'Session-Id' each time you start that process.

Comment: thanks for response. I do set `Session-Id` for each request with value generated from file name so it is the same for each request within the same process.

Comment: Ok, but since you generate from the name vs being unique (like a GUID), did you had previous request using that Session-Id but not for that process?

Comment: Honestly I didn't even think about it. Between tests I did some changes in requests. I've changed `Session-Id` so it won't repeat and file was uploaded successfully. @cyrille, thanks for the tip :)